# How to make stacked column chart percentages exceed 100% in highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts, frontend

I am trying to make a [highcharts stacked column percentage chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-percent) go above 100%. I am using the stacked columns to gauge certain metrics and when they "overflow" I would like the associated column to go above 100%.

[image]

For example, the red section of the "pop" bar in this attached chart should go above 100%

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone elses future reference, there was not "built in" solution to this problem using the stacked percentage feature of highcharts. I had to build a normal stacked chart and just convert the data and Y axis label to percentage format.

Comment: Could you supply your example as jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: It's a normal stacked chart, I just changed the y axis to percent formatting with format '{value}%', and then set the y values of the stacked columns to percents that add up to 100. Except on the right column for this chart I had the blue column set to 100 and the red to 17 so that column would add up to 117%

Comment: Unfortunately this opions is not possible, but you can disable percent stacking and calculate your data into percentage. Then modify labels by labelFormatter and add %.

Comment: @seb Yes this is what I ended up doing.